# Using box2d with libgdx on Ubuntu and I've been following tutorials online. Gravity doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

1./*The main class where resolution and methods are initialised*/

```
        public class Flappy2 extends ApplicationAdapter {

            public static final int WIDTH = 480;
            public static final int HEIGHT = 800;

            public static final String TITLE = "Flappy 2";
            private GameStateManager gsm;


            private SpriteBatch batch;


            @Override
            public void create () {
                batch = new SpriteBatch();
                gsm = new GameStateManager();
                Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
                gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));
            }

            @Override
            public void render () {

                Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); //update method  
                gsm.render(batch);
            }

            @Override
            public void dispose () {
                batch.dispose();

            }
        }
```

// Bird.class

```
        public class Bird {
            private static final int GRAVITY = -15;
            private Vector3 position;
            private Vector3 velocity;
            private Texture bird;

            public Bird(int x, int y){
                position = new Vector3(x,y,0);
                velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
                bird = new Texture("bird.png");
            }

            public void update(float dt){
                velocity.add(0, GRAVITY, 0);
                velocity.scl(dt);
                velocity.add(0, velocity.y, 0);
                velocity.scl(1/dt);

            }

            public Texture getTexture() {
                return bird;
            }

            public Vector3 getPosition() {
                return position;
            }

            public void jump(){
                velocity.y = 250;  //the on-click jump
            }
        }
```

//  GameStateManager.class

```
        public class GameStateManager {

            private Stack<State> states;
            public GameStateManager(){
                states = new Stack<State>();
            }

            public void push(State state){
                states.push(state);
            }

            public void pop(){
                states.pop();
            }

            public void set(State state){
                states.pop();
                states.push(state);
            }

            public void update(float dt){
                states.peek().update(dt);
            }

            public void render(SpriteBatch sb){
                states.peek().render(sb);
            }


        }
```

2./*Menu state is working fine */

```
        public class MenuState extends State {
            private Texture background;
            private Texture playBtn;

            public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
                super(gsm);
                background = new Texture("bg.jpg");
                playBtn    = new Texture("playbtn.png"); /*menu state button*/
            }

            @Override
            public void handleInput() {
                if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) { /*input from user*/
                    gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
                    dispose();
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void update(float dt) {
                handleInput();

            }

            @Override
            public void dispose() {
                background.dispose();
                playBtn.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
                sb.begin();
                sb.draw(background,0,0, Flappy2.WIDTH, Flappy2.HEIGHT);
                sb.draw(playBtn, (Flappy2.WIDTH/2) - (playBtn.getWidth()/2), Flappy2.HEIGHT/2);
                sb.end();
            }
        }
```

3./*play-state class(after menu state)*/

```
        public class PlayState extends State {
                    private Bird bird;


            public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
                super(gsm);
                bird = new Bird(50,300);
                cam.setToOrtho(false, Flappy2.WIDTH/2, Flappy2.HEIGHT/2);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleInput() {
                if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){  /*taking input from user*/
                    bird.jump();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void update(float dt) {
                handleInput();
                bird.update(dt);
            }

            @Override
            public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
                sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
                sb.begin();
                sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x, bird.getPosition().y);
                sb.end();

            }

            @Override
            public void dispose() {

            }
        }
```

/*4.The abstract State class*/

```
        public abstract class State {
            protected OrthographicCamera cam;
            protected Vector3 mouse;
            protected GameStateManager gsm;

            protected State(GameStateManager gsm){
                this.gsm    = gsm;
                cam         = new OrthographicCamera(); /*Camera init*/
                mouse       = new Vector3();/*vector3 object initialised*/
            }

            protected abstract void handleInput();/*method handles i/p*/
            public abstract void update(float dt);/*takes a deltatime argument*/
            public abstract void render(SpriteBatch sb);
            public abstract void dispose();
        }

  /*  Build.Gradle */   /*build gradle file */

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        apply plugin: "eclipse"
        apply plugin: "idea"

        version = '1.0'
        ext {
            appName = "Flappy2"
            gdxVersion = '1.9.4'
            roboVMVersion = '2.2.0'
            box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
            ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
            aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        }
    }

    project(":desktop") {
        apply plugin: "java"


        dependencies {
            compile project(":core")
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        }
    }

    project(":android") {
        apply plugin: "android"

        configurations { natives }

        dependencies {
            compile project(":core")
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
            natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        }
    }

    project(":core") {
        apply plugin: "java"


        dependencies {
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
            compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        }
    }

    tasks.eclipse.doLast {
        delete ".project"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, velocity isn't being applied to the bird's position anywhere. You're drawing the bird at bird.getPosition(), but position is always (50, 300).

Add the calculated velocity to the position in Bird's update method.

```
position.add(velocity);
```

Comment: but now the bird goes flying off the screen even if I set velocity.y=5.

Comment: Mess around with the gravity value rather than the velocity.